# ajax and php pettition satuts cancelled after x attempts

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

im making and update in mysql table when button click, the problem is ajax jquery not working sometimes. It works fine and somehow after x attempts it stop working and stars cancelling my petitions

the problem is after x number of attempts the success part of ajax object is not being used and im getting the STATUS (canceled) from network.

Comment: You're looking for AJAX

Comment: You'll need an AJAX request in your else portion. Also I'd suggest against using PHP to echo out your JavaScript

Comment: how could i execute javascript without echo, within php?

Comment: @Hbassuki Like this: `?> <script>// Your JS goes here</script><?php`

Comment: @mike thanks im new to programming! so it doesnt matter how many times i open and close php tags , its always better than using the echo?? THANKS

Comment: @Hbassuki No, not always better. But if you have a big block of HTML or JS that you want to echo, then yes. That way you should also get syntax highlighting if your editor supports it.

Comment: @Mike great! thank you a lot!!! yes im using ATOM and when using echo highlighting is not supported and its a bummer !! haha great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass these values to hidden fields. These fields are called through ajax to send data to next-page to update.

```
<input type='hidden' value="<?echo $costo_sem;?>" class="costosemanal">
<input type='hidden' value="<?echo $fi;?>" class="fechai">
<input type='hidden' value="<?echo $ff;?>" class="fechaf">

  echo "<script>
            var r = confirm('OK to update, CANCEL to do nothing');
            if(r === false){
             document.location.href = 'costos.php';
           }else{
            var costosemanal=$('.costosemanal').val();
            var fechai=$('.fechai').val();
            var fechaf=$('.fechaf').val();
            $.ajax({url:'UpdatePage.php?costosemanal='+costosemanal+'&fechai='+fechai+'&fechaf='+fechaf,cache:false,success:function(result){
                 alert('Updated');
            }});
           }
           </script>";
```

Add one UpdatePage.php to update your query.

**UpdatePage.php**

```
<?
$costosemanal=$_GET['costosemanal'];
$fechai=$_GET['fechai'];
$fechaf=$_GET['fechaf'];

$update = "UPDATE tbl_costos SET costo_semanal = '$costosemanal' WHERE fechai = '$fechai' AND fechaf ='$fechaf' ";

//Write Mysql Command To Update This Query

?>
```

Comment: thanks!!! with a bit modifications i was able to do it!!

Comment: @Hbassuki. Reliefed. Yeah, see problem is we don't have much idea what programmer is thinking. So, we can't give exact code. 'm Happy that it worked.

Comment: yes!!! its hard because im new to programing, and specially ajax

Comment: i have just one doubt...Im getting SOME of my ajax request canceled... Example: i make 1st request, it makes the update, but when then i do it again, gets cancelled an error log comes out

Comment: show me that error log ? @Hbassuki

Comment: on the $.ajax( error: function(){ alert("error") }), and on chrome the STATUS text is CANCELED, on my network tab

Comment: weird that i can update sometimes, but others i get CANCELED status on network

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.removeItem').click(function (event) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you?')) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'myUrl',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                // data stuff here
             },
             success: function () {
                // does some stuff here...
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Use above code inside url there must be php page url...